# How do pools calculate the "expected daily earnings"?

Tags: mining, block-reward

I've been looking at the "expected daily earnings per 100MH/s" on the hiveon.net pool and it was 0.006eth to more than 0.007eth for the past few weeks, but very recently it's gone down to a lot of the times less than 0.005eth. I also mine a little bit and the average earnings seem to match. The past 2 days have had way less earnings than usual.
I'm struggling to understand why it changed so drastically.
I looked at the etherscan.io block explorer and it seems that the average block reward has stayed almost the same for the entire time and the network hashrate / difficulty didn't go up substantially either. Is there something more to the expected daily earnings per mh than just the total network hashrate and the block reward? does the mining speed slow down substantially if the difficulty increases slightly?

Comment: If you look at average difficulty on Etherscan https://etherscan.io/chart/difficulty in the last month it went from 4.1 (Jan 17) to 5.1 Th (Feb 17), and it was 3.5 Th on Dec 17.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I too am new to mining and running a small pc rig. It gives out about 61-62mh/s and yesterday on Hiveon pool I was getting about 13-18.5 USD/per day for the same mh/s. I check it again today and now it shows me 4.5usd/day as the expected earning. I wonder where these huge fluctuations are coming from. Even though my reported hash rate and and no of shares submitted are roughly of the same frequency. I do not know much about block rewards but even if I did, I doubt if it would contribute a huge 10-15usd/day difference in expected earnings. I ask this as a follow up doubt if anybody else knows how to account it for.